# Use an existing disk in a persitent volume claim

Tags: kubernetes, backup, azure-aks, persistent-volumes

I have an (AKS) Kubernetes cluster running a couple of pods. Those pods have dynamic persistent volume claims. An example is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pvc
  namespace: prd
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: custom-azure-disk-retain
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
```

The disks are Azure Managed Disks and are backupped (snapshots) with the Azure backup center. In the backup center I can create a disk from a snapshot.

Here is my question: how can I use the new disk in the PVC? Because I don't think I can patch the PV with a new DiskURI.

What I figured out myself is how to use the restored dik directly as a volume. But if I'm not mistaken this does not use a PVC anymore meaning I can not benefit from dynamically resizing the disk.

I'm using kustomize, here is how I can link the restored disk directoy in the deployment's yaml:

```
- op: remove
  path: "/spec/template/spec/volumes/0/persistentVolumeClaim"
- op: add
  path: "/spec/template/spec/volumes/0/azureDisk"
  value: {kind: Managed, diskName: mysql-restored-disk, diskURI: <THE_URI>}
```

Some people will tell me to use [Velero](https://velero.io/) but we're not ready for that yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are using dynamic provisioning and then you want to hardcode DiskURIs? With this you also have to bind pods to nodes. This will be a nightmare when you have a disaster recovery case.

To be honest, use Velereo :) Invest the time to get comfortable with it, your MTTR will thank you.

Here is a quick start article with AKS: https://dzone.com/articles/setup-velero-on-aks